# Why does changing mobx observable state variable inside a react component render is not throwing invariant violation error as like in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx, react-dom, mobx-react

Why does changing mobx observable state variable inside a react component render is not throwing invariant violation error as like in react

## Case 1:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count: 0
  };
  render() {
    this.setState({
      count: this.state.count + 1
    });
    console.log("hi");
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.count}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <Counter/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

The above snippet is throwing error as expected:

```
Invariant Violation
Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

However the below snippet should also throw as the same error right? but its actually not.

## Case 2:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable, action } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";


@observer
class Counter extends React.Component {
  @observable count = 0;

  render() {
    this.count = this.count + 1 
    return (
      <div>
        <p>{this.count}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <Counter/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

***Why is it that any error is not being thrown similar to react?***
***Any explanation for it?***

## Case 3: An observation

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import { observable } from "mobx";
import { observer } from "mobx-react";


@observer
class Counter extends React.Component {
  @observable count = 0;

  changeCount = () => {
    this.count = this.count + 1 
  }
  render() {
    this.count = this.count + 1 
    return (
      <div onClick={this.changeCount}>
        <p>{this.count}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(
  <Counter/>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

This will not throw error on initial render
But it will throw error when we click counter div

```
Error
[mobx] Side effects like changing state are not allowed at this point. Are you trying to modify state from, for example, the render function of a React component? Tried to modify: Counter@259.count
```